# Android Install button inactive, cancel works

Tags: installation

Unable to tap on the INSTALL button for an app (that I created). Cancel button works fine.

I have looked into other answers and they all seem to be talking about screen dimming / blue light filter apps - I am not using any screen dimming or blue-light filter app/tool, or have any such settings on (that I am aware of).

My phone is an Honor 6X. Its a phonegap/ cordova app that I created for my personal use. Have been using it for months, and have installed updated versions many times with no issue. Few days ago, while using the app - it got stuck (it was writing a lot of data into an SQL database) when it sorta hung up for a long time. So I closed the app - and after that it stopped working. It just won't start again. (I guess the SQL file got corrupted because I forcefully closed it when it was still writing data)..

I uninstalled it, and when I tried to reinstall again - the INSTALL button won't work - seems to be inactive.

I then changed the app ID (reverse domain id), app versions etc - and tried to install it as a new app - but that didn't work either.

Finally, I downloaded another third party app - (which I had successfully installed on my phone before) - and same issue - unable to tap the install button. So it looks like I am unable to install any kind of third-party app, not just that app. Can somebody help?

Comment: Are you able to give runtime permissions to app?

Comment: Try installing with ADB Shell. If the problem persits, you might need to perform a factory reset that may solve it.

Comment: Do you have any type of screen filter app switched on? In such cases, these problems do occur, like in my case.

Comment: Well, this might sound stupid but when you are on the install screen lock your phone and then unlock it(by pressing the power button) and then see if it works. It worked on my Amazon Kindle fire.

Comment: @global_warming - how do I know?  During the setup - it shows a grey bullet, and says - this app will get the following permissions (read and write into SD card). Cancel OR Install. But I am unable to tap the install button here. It used to work fine before - this same app with the same permission requirements.

Comment: @esQmo_ thanks. Looking into it. Will update on how that goes..

Comment: @WrichikBasu - no, I don't have any such apps. I do have a option for it in settings (and I have used it in the past as well), but its turned off right now. I played with many options in the 'Display' settings to see if turning something on or off will make it work. But no luck.

Comment: @AnuragThakur thanks for the unique tip. just tried it a few times. but no luck :(

Comment: Did ADB install worked? As suggest by esQmo_?

Comment: @AnuragThakur - not yet - still looking into it and figuring things - will give it a try sometime later and will update here..

Comment: @AD1 I'm sorry should have made it clear. Can you tap on allow/deny during runtime permissions for any app? Generally that happens when "draw over other apps" is on. Under apps->configure apps->special access->draw over other apps

Comment: @global_warming - yes, I am able to allow/deny various runtime permissions for other apps. I have many apps that use the "draw over other apps" permission. I am not sure my app (the one that stopped working & won't install again - let us call it MBMT) needed or had that permission.

Comment: No, the problem doesn't lies with your app "MBMT". `Package Manager` is used to install apps means you won't be able to install any app. I would suggest you to revoke 'draw over other apps' from all apps that are allowed (have draw over other apps ON) and then try installing.

Comment: SQLite has transactional integrity, so force-closing the app in the middle of a transaction can't corrupt the database file. It just loses the in-progress write. But perhaps the file was already corrupt for some other reason, and that's why the write was hanging in the first place.

Comment: @global_warming - thank a lot, will give it a try. Have 220+ apps installed on my phone, so might take a while for me to do that..

Comment: @DanHulme - oh, yes probably..

Comment: @esQmo_  it worked. Installing it using adb shell worked, and was really simple too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I helped :D

Answer (score 1):

Anurag's suggestion worked for me. From the install screen lock your phone with your power button then unlocked and voila there's the install button

Answer (score -1):

Same problem as I had.. My trick is to DL the app then open download folder tap the app, scroll down to the no install..  Hit back then tap on the install screen u see.. Voila it now allows Install